# Insert request.session in class based Generic view in Django

Tags: python, django, session, detailview

I'm trying to use request.session to create a 'recent' session key and add the product pages visited by the user to make it accesible in the template, here is my view, what would you guys recommend, I can't seem to go about doing this

```
class ProductDetail(DetailView):
    model = Producto
    template_name = 'productos/product_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(ProductDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add in a QuerySet of featured products
        context['product_list'] = Producto.objects.filter(featured=True).exclude(pk=self.object.pk)
        return context
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? You have the method there to add items to the context. what is your question?

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear, I can't seem to get handle of the session object inside the view

Comment: It's just `self.request.session`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to Daniel Roseman for the clarification on how to call session from the class based generic view

```
class ProductDetail(DetailView):
    model = Producto
    template_name = 'productos/product_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(ProductDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if not 'recent' in self.request.session or not self.request.session['recent']:
            self.request.session['recent'] = [self.object.pk]
        else:
            recentList = self.request.session['recent']
            recentList.append(self.object.pk)
            self.request.session['recent'] = recentList
        # Add in a QuerySet of featured products
        context['product_list'] = Producto.objects.filter(featured=True).exclude(pk=self.object.pk)
        context['recent_list'] = Producto.objects.filter(pk__in=recentList)
        return context
```