# How to use Django Sessions Framework in generic views to send data to another

Tags: django, django-generic-views, django-sessions, django-permissions

In my Django application, I am trying to use sessions to store a variable in my class view and later use it to send it to a function view.

In the past I have used sessions on function views and now I am trying to use it on a class view.

```
class someView(CreateView):
    form_class = myForm
    template_name = 'myTemplate.html'
    ...
    ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        request.session['my_var'] = '1234'
        return context
```

Than I am trying to capture the session variable in another view like this:

```
def fnView(request):
    data = {}
    new_var = request.session['my_var']
    data = {'key1': new_var}
    return render(request, 'fnVwTemplt.html', data)
```

And in the template I am trying to display the variable like this:

```
{{ key1 }}
```

However I am coming up with the following message in the browser:

> KeyError at ...
>
> 'my_var'

It is evident that the variable is not getting stored in the session variable.

**What I am doing wrong?**

**PS**. Apologies, if my query is not lucid enough.

Comment: `It is evident that the variable is not getting stored in the session variable.` had you checked session storage in the browser from someView `myTemplate.html` ? to make sure that your variable actually saved in the session

Comment: if you want to avoid error from a key better to use `request.session.get('my_var', None)`

Comment: @LinhNguyen - Thanks so much for your reply. I tried to use `request.session.get('my_var, None)`, however getting `None` in my template. And, where exactly do I check in the browser for **session storage**?

Comment: Yeah, got it. It should be in `Developr Tools > Application > Storage > Session Storage > Site url`. No, there is **no entry there**. So it seems that the variable is not getting stored at all.

Comment: so the problem is from get_context_data, try changing it to use `self.request.session['my_var'] = '1234'` instead

Comment: Still getting `None`. On a hunch I thought of checking if the app is hitting the view `someView` at all. I changed the `get_context_data` code (misspelt `self` to `selfx`). And still there is no `Error`. Neither in the terminal on module `save` nor when calling the view. Something very wrong here...

Comment: well i can't see any problem as the method to set session variable is correct [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.__setitem__), did your `get_context_data` to run in the template view ?

Comment: Could you please explain *did your get_context_data to run in the template view ?* If I am getting it correct, I am using it on a `CreateView` (as shown in my original post) alongwith **PermissionRequiredMixin** (to check for user permission on the model).

Comment: sorry i'm not familiar with using generic view but your way of using is the same as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21904529/11225821) maybe you can look into it

Comment: @LinhNguyen - Thanks for taking time out for me. I will check the one suggested by you.

Comment: i think you need to override the context first for get_context_data to work. Add `context = super(someView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)` in `get_context_data` before return

Comment: @LinhNguyen - I am sorry but I just realized that I already have `context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)` which I failed to reproduce in my question. I have now changed it to `context = super(someView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)`, as suggested by you. Unfortunately still not getting the session data.